# Chrome and Safari on iOS 12.4 doesn't set cookies timeously

Tags: ios, web, cookies

In a web page I set a cookie when the page loads then check a condition and immediately redirect to a second page on the same site where I read the cookie. The cookie is not set when I arrive at the second page. The above functionality works on desktop browsers and it worked in iOS 12.3.1 without any changes to the site. After upgrade to 12.4 it stopped working, but still worked on a 12.3.1 device.
Any thoughts?

Comment: check if the "block thirdparty cookies" is enabled in ios.

Comment: How are you setting the cookie?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a comprehensive answer since there are missing pieces in the question.

**#1**, the issue often appears when the user serves a page from a local file.

> Ex: `file:///C:/project/index.html`.

Cookies require a web server to be running to be set. Meaning at the very least you need to serve it from `http://localhost/index.html`.

**#2**, You are setting the path in the cookie. Meaning the cookie is limited to only one path.

```
// Example:
document.cookie = "key=value; expires=; path=/my/path/"
```

Here the cookie will only be valid in the declared url path.

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue here.

Comment: What is your url structure. and how are you setting cookies then? @dataphile

Comment: I'm using Angular. Did you see the part where it works on desktop browsers and 12.3.1 devices?

Comment: It would have been helpful to include angular as a tag.

Comment: It's not limited to Angular and as such the problem has nothing to do with Angular. The fact that it's running on iOS should tell you that it's not a `file:///C:...` thing.